# How to avoid DATEDIFF in where clause T-SQL optimization

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, sql-server-2014

I would like to optimize my T-SQL query by removing `DATEDIFF` from `WHERE` clause. My query has this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(hh, DATE1, DATE2) > HOUR
```

`DATE1` and `DATE2` both comes from different tables, I can optimize if I want to compare `DATEDIFF` with `GETDATE()` against any column but here, I have both columns from tables.

Is there any way to optimize this or any other alternative for `DATEDIFF` here?

Comment: DATEDIFF is a very fast operation what is your Actual Execution Plan is showing you? You may be looking at the wrong place to optimise

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. DATEDIFF is fast - I also reviewed few other blogs here but just for optimization purpose, I want to avoid functions in where clause. my query is performing fine.

Comment: you could have it as a calculated column within your table. But some people do not like having calculated columns. It will not give you better performance but it wont be in your WHERE clause if that's important to you.

Comment: Ok, I visited few links to avoid functions in WHERE clause, please correct me if I am wrong, and what to do in my scenario to avoid DATEDIFF in where for 2 columns. See this blog. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/12/sql-server-avoid-using-function-in-where-clause-scan-to-seek/

Comment: if you are really sure,if this isn't a case of premature optimization,you can insert the datediff result from two tables into a temp and query it,like this you can have better stats as well

Comment: @k-s that is true once your attributes are wrapped inside a function then you wont be able to take full advantage of indexes on those columns.

Comment: I suggest you post the entire query and execution plan.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
WHERE DATE2 - DATE1 > HOUR/24
```